# Guid as Id in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

The [RavenDb documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/basic-operations/saving-new-document) states:

> Numeric or Guid Id properties are supported and will work seamlessly. In this case, RavenDB will automatically make the translation between the inner string ID to the numeric or Guid value shown in the entity and back.

I have stored the following objects:

```
class A
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid BId { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have then created the following projection:

```
class AB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }       // This should be the Id of A
    public Guid BId { get; set; }      // This should be the Id of B
    public string BName { get; set; }  // This should be the name of B
}
```

I have created the following index to create the projection:

```
class MyIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<AB>
{
    public MyIndex()
    {
        Map = docs =>
            from d in docs
            select new
            {
                d.Id,
                d.BId,
                BName = string.Empty
            };

        TransformResults = (database, results) =>
            from r in results
            let b = database.Load<B>("bs/" + r.BId.ToString())
            select new
            {
                r.Id,
                r.BId,
                BName = b.Name
            };
    }
}
```

When I use the following query:

```
session.Query<AB, MyIndex>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == guid);
```

I get this exception:

> Error converting value "bs/cc0a65ae-dd36-4437-8a57-fa20b91eeef7" to type 'System.Guid'. Path 'Id'.

**Questions:**

1. It is caused by the conversion in my projection since the `Id` is a string there and not my Guid anymore. However, leaving it out will not return the Id. What must I do?
2. I have to use the string building `"bs/" + r.BId.ToString()` to load the related doc. Is there a way not having to do this? Is there some sort of function that would resolve the doc tag for me?
3. Is there a generic way to strip out the document tag altogether?

**My constraints.**

I will generate the Guid and cannot let RavenDb generate it for me. I know that the Document ID in reality is string, but I really need to use a Guid that I create. I would prefer to own the `Id` property of my entities.

I'm using Raven.Client 1.0.972

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using a MultiMap/Reduce Index, but you will need some hackery:

1) You will need to reduce using strings, not guids.  You can still get the values back as guids in your AB class, as I will demonstrate below.

2) You can't call the first property of your AB class "Id", as raven will try to translate it to "__document_id".   So call it "AId" and it will work fine.

3) In the mapping phase, you have to manipulate the strings yourself to strip off the document key prefix.

Here's a sample program that puts it all together.  This demonstrates that it does indeed work, but I think it also shows why Ayende prefers string identifiers so you don't have to deal with this kind of mess.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Raven.Client.Document;
using Raven.Client.Indexes;

namespace RavenScratchTest
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      var documentStore = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080" };
      documentStore.Initialize();
      IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(Program).Assembly, documentStore);

      using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
      {
        var b = new B { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Foo" };
        var a = new A { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), BId = b.Id };

        session.Store(a);
        session.Store(b);

        session.SaveChanges();
      }

      using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
      {
        var a = session.Query<A>().Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults()).First();
        var b = session.Query<B>().Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults()).First();

        Console.WriteLine("A:  Id = {0}", a.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("   BId = {0}", a.BId);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("B:  Id = {0}", b.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("  Name = {0}", b.Name);
        Console.WriteLine();

        var guid = a.Id;
        var ab = session.Query<AB, MyIndex>().Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())
          .FirstOrDefault(t => t.AId == guid);

        if (ab == null)
          Console.WriteLine("AB: NULL");
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine("AB:  AId = {0}", ab.AId);
          Console.WriteLine("   BId = {0}", ab.BId);
          Console.WriteLine("   BName = {0}", ab.BName);
          Console.WriteLine();
        }
      }

      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Done.");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

  class A
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid BId { get; set; }
  }

  class B
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  class AB
  {
    public Guid AId { get; set; }
    public Guid BId { get; set; }
    public string BName { get; set; }
  }

  class MyIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<MyIndex.ReduceResult>
  {
    public MyIndex()
    {
      AddMap<A>(docs => from a in docs
                select new
                {
                  AId = a.Id.ToString().Split('/')[1],
                  a.BId,
                  BName = (string)null
                });

      AddMap<B>(docs => from b in docs
                select new
                {
                  AId = (string)null,
                  BId = b.Id.ToString().Split('/')[1],
                  BName = b.Name
                });

      Reduce = results => from result in results
                group result by result.BId
                into g
                select new
                  {
                    g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AId != null).AId,
                    BId = g.Key,
                    g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BName != null).BName
                  };
    }

    internal class ReduceResult
    {
      public string AId { get; set; }
      public string BId { get; set; }
      public string BName { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that in my sample, WaitForNonStaleResults is just because it's a console test app.

Comment: Sorry - I just realized you said you are using 1.0.972 (stable).  Unfortunately, you need the unstable (1.2.x) branch for this to work.  I'm not sure exactly what issue it was that fixed it, but it does not work with 1.0.960 or 1.0.972.

Comment: So this kind of proves Ayendes point then :) 
I will definitely look into the HiLo usage as that changes everything.
Thanks for an excellent answer!

Comment: Note that this was written in 2012.  In newer versions of RavenDB, you should use [`LoadDocument`](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/static-indexes/indexing-related-documents) instead of multimap/reduce.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide an ID to RavenDB explicitly upon saving:

```
session.Store(doc, explicitIdValueString);
```

The `explicitIdValueString` can be a Guid string. This value will be used to identify the document within the entire database and will not be prefixed by a type tag name. You can also customized the tag name, or the ID generation strategy all together by overriding conventions on `IDocumentStore.Conventions` such as `FindTypeTagName` which is a `Func<Type, string>`.

Comment: Nowadays, RavenDb has been changing a little. In 4.1 version you can set the object Id with `string.Empty`, then RavenDb will create a Guid for you. [Documentation](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/csharp/client-api/document-identifiers/working-with-document-identifiers)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that while RavenDB can deal with numeric / integer on the client, but on the server side, RavenDB uses string ids.

In general, it isn't recommended to use Guids / numeric ids.

Comment: I'm hitting this problem badly too. (1) `Numeric or Guid Id properties are supported and will work seamlessly.` (2) This is a basic requirement for a database, especially if you are in an asynchronous architecture.

Comment: ...is there nothing more that could be done in the .NET client to make using Guids more usable? Thanks Ayende.

Comment: I'm in an asynchronous architecture and most things are built on Guids as identifiers. 
My plan eventually is to write documents that are isolated in terms of aggregate roots, so that I can execute projections in parallel. The projection features in Raven makes it perfect for the task, except for the Id strategy. I hope there is a combination of conventions or something that would make this possible, but I haven't succeeded yet. Conventions seems to apply to the client and wont make any difference in the server/indexing, right?

Comment: I too am in an asynchronous CQRS architecture, and get by just fine with string identifiers and letting Raven generate IDs for me.  The trick is to generate an ID ahead of time (when the command is sent), and then using that ID when saving the document (when the command is handled).  Here's a handy extension method I use to achieve this:  https://gist.github.com/3823390  You might think it's inefficient, but because Raven's Hilo assigns Ids in blocks that are cached by the client, it works out quite nicely.

Comment: Just to clarify on my last comment, the only reason to do this is so you can return the Id to the caller.  If your caller doesn't need to know, then the command can be sent without an Id and we can just let raven generate it as normal when stored.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have Users and you want to generate guid identifiers for these.

```
new User { Id = "users/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") }
```

For sanity purposes, in documents i eagerly create keys for I set them up as immutable.

```
public class User
{
    public User(Guid? guid = null)
    {
        IdPart = (guid ?? Guid.NewGuid()).ToString("N")
    }

    string IdPart { get; }
    string Id => $"Users/{IdPart}"
```

Sometimes IdPart actually a whole key. Suppose we have "Users/abc". If a user has a Project. I will commonly create a document similar to:

```
public class Project
{
    public User(Guid? userId = null)
    {
        UserId = "Users/" + (guid ?? Guid.NewGuid()).ToString("N");
        Id = $"{UserId}/project/"

    }
```

Note the trailing `project/` this will inform raven to create a HiLo value after the slash.

This concept can be used to easily intermix both assigned identifiers, natural identifiers, and sequence/hilo/identity keys while promoting readable identifiers as opposed to `1`. `1` is what? But `User/abc/project/1`, i can tell you what that is. The first project created by abc

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<AB>
{
    public MyIndex()
    {
        Map = docs =>
            from d in docs
            select new
            {
                d.Id,
                d.BId,
                BName = string.Empty
            };

        TransformResults = (database, results) =>
            from r in results
            let b = database.Load<B>("bs/" + r.BId.ToString())
            select new
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse(r.Id.ToString().Split('/').Last()),
                r.BId,
                BName = b.Name
            };
    }
}
```