# RavenDB versioning bundle and object with Guid id gives an exception at GetRevisionsFor

Tags: c#, versioning, ravendb

I have been using RavenDb 2.5 together with Versioning Bundle. 
It worked perfect until I had to change domain model **Id** from **int** to **Guid**.

Here is my class (a bit shortened though)

```
[Serializable]
public class BookTree : IBookTreeComponent 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OwnerEmail { get; set; }

}
```

Getting the latest revision as well as list of revisions works perfectly.
But then program get stumbled across

```
session.Advanced.GetRevisionsFor<BookTree>("BookTrees/" + tree1.Id, 0, 25).ToList();
```

I am getting the following exception

```
 An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in  
 Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll but was not handled in user code

 Additional information: Could not convert document 
 BookTrees/5a84823f-dbe3-4c35-9010-672223baa330/revisions/1 to entity of type
 some.namespace.BookTree
```

Where inner exception is:

```
 {"Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes
 (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)."}
```

After looking into **GetRevisionsFor** extension method:

```
    public static T[] GetRevisionsFor1<T>(this ISyncAdvancedSessionOperation session, string id, int start, int pageSize)
    {
        var inMemoryDocumentSessionOperations = ((InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations)session);
        var jsonDocuments = ((DocumentSession)session).DatabaseCommands.StartsWith(id + "/revisions/", null, start, pageSize);
        return jsonDocuments
            .Select(inMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity<T>)
            .ToArray();
    }
```

I have found out that that I am actually getting jsonDocument, but then exception occurs somewhere in this method **inMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity**

Nonetheless, as I mentioned before it worked perfectly with integer Ids.

Any ideas what went wrong or how to make it work with Guid ids?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682550/guid-as-id-in-ravendb?rq=1 help?

Comment: Brian, nope unfortunately it does not.

There is a bug in version module and it can not parse GUID from the real ID that document has, i.e. Revision bungle can not parse "BookTrees/5a84823f-dbe3-4c35-9010-672223baa330/revisions/1" and get the guid out of that string. 

I have solved the problem by rewriting extension methods for session class.
I will probably upload the solution here.